# GIMP variable sunburst gradient

Tags: gimp, gradient

I'm new to GIMP (trying to finally move over from PSP9!)
I want to create a sunburst gradient with a variable number of repeats either by repeat count or angle (e.g. 4 repeats = 90 degrees).  Is there a way to do this without adding dozens of points to a gradient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with a rectangular image that you fill with a repeated linear gradient (using the repetition option of the blend tool of course, set to `Sawtooth`):

[image]

And then apply `Filters>Distorts>Polar coordinates` with `To polar` ticked:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that - it's worked pretty well.  Would be nice to able to do this and have a slider to change the number of repeats but it gives me something to work with.

Comment: Looking at how to multiply a gradient so that you could easily multiply a gradient for use with a conical blend but don't hold your breath.

Comment: @JimHudd - you can change the number of repeats by [shortening or lengthening the gradient line](https://imgur.com/fsClUcd).

Comment: @BillyKerr I tried that but it only worked for linear gradients, not conical